# Проблема с тестами при решении задачи JS

Tags: javascript

Решаю задачу на Codewars. Нужно написать свои тесты, которые я написал. Вроде всё проходит, но при проверки кода с тестами разработчика выдаёт ошибку. Я взял те строки, которые даются в тесте и сделал из них переменные и проверил на своём коде. Всё работает. Не пойму почему не проходит тест, подскажите пожалуйста.[image: Codewars задача]

Comment: попробуйте return использовать

Answer (score 0):

Функция должна возвращать какое-либо значение. В данном случае функция должна вернуть строку, где слова разбиты по знаку подчёркивания. У вас функция ничего не возвращает, поэтому и неверено.